# Hosting a Laravel 4.2 project with PHP 5.6 on a hosting server 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel-4, hosting, web-hosting, php-5.6

> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 411

This error above I've faced on a free hosting service that uses PHP 5.3

I'm trying also on another paid service with PHP 5.3 and I'm getting the 500 Internal Server Error, and I made sure my routes and paths are good to go. (The `index.php` in the public folder, and the `/bootstrap/path.php` files are good to go with DIR URIs).

Now I'm sure I will keep getting these kind of errors and my app won't work unless I host it on a service with PHP 5.6, but I was hoping there would be a way that I could downgrade my Laravel version or PHP version for some kind of `Backward Compatibility`.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My files are in the root directory, and there isn't any folder named `public_html` and so the files originally in the `Laravel/public` folder are dispersed in the root directory and my other application files and folders are in a folder in the root directory.

Any suggestions or help would really be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide the `public_html` folder tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come over this problem with editing the `.htaccess` file within the `/public_html` folder of the server.

**OR**

By using the **cPanel**'s **Redirects** and make it Redirect the server to the

`domain.com/{if it's inside a folder inside the public_html}/index.php`

and then **ALL Routes and links worked** perfectly fine.

If you want to change the **URL** and use `Pretty URLs` refer to the **Laravel Documentations** under `Configuration`.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4.2 requires PHP 5.4.

> Laravel 4.2 requires PHP 5.4 or greater. This upgraded PHP requirement
>   allows us to use new PHP features such as traits to provide more
>   expressive interfaces for tools like Laravel Cashier. PHP 5.4 also
>   brings significant speed and performance improvements over PHP 5.3.

Please see this for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/releases

Your question is quite unclear, because you first state that you get the 500 Internal Server Error when using PHP 5.6 (in the title and, assumedly, the tag), but then you say that "[the] app won't work unless [you] host it on a service with PHP 5.6".

Comment: As you can read in my error reporting blockquote "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." &&&& "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." I've researched enough to give up and figure out that back compatibility is the only solution for hosting servers like these... so are you gonna give me a lecture on the improvements of PHP 5.4? Don't you think that's why I'm using PHP 5.6 even, or Laravel. 
Thank you. @Mike

Comment: Point of the matter is that you tried on 5.3, which is why I mentioned it. And no, I was not lecturing you, I was giving substance to my answer.